# Sendmail entry in /etc/aliases that modifies the email header before sending it out?

Tags: bash, sendmail, sed

I'm using Sendmail  I want to create an alias in /etc/aliases, that modifies the To: line before sending out the message .  I assume I need some sort of script or command that the email is piped into. Any suggestions?

A very basic modification is needed.  I need to change an address from foo@foobar to foo@barfoo.  Thanks!